# log4j - StringMatchFilter still logging unmatched logs

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Hope anyone could help me with this issue, so basically I am using log4j-1.2.17 and sorry, I can't update it to log4j2. 
As the title suggests, I need to do the following,

1. I am trying to create an **audit.log** file which only logs information that has a certain string element (e.g., USER ACTION) and doesn't log anything else.
2. I have another **operations.log** that will log everything but not the one with String **USER ACTION**

My **log4j.properties** file looks something like this,

```
log4j.logger.com.ssl=INFO, Output 
log4j.logger.com.ssl=INFO, Audit

log4j.appender.Output=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Output.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.Output.File=/var/log/operational/operations.log
log4j.appender.Output.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Output.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %m (%c)%n 
log4j.appender.Output.Threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.Output.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.Output.filter.1.StringToMatch=USER ACTION
log4j.appender.Output.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=false
log4j.appender.Output.filter=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter

log4j.appender.Audit=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Audit.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.Audit.File=/var/log/operational/audit.log
log4j.appender.Audit.Threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.Audit.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Audit.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %m (%c)%n
log4j.appender.Audit.filter.1=org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter
log4j.appender.Audit.filter.1.StringToMatch=USER ACTION
log4j.appender.Audit.filter.1.AcceptOnMatch=true
log4j.appender.Audit.filter=org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter
```

Inside the **Java Code**, I have something like this,

```
private static final String AUDIT_LOG_PREFIX = "USER ACTION";
logger.info("Just testing if this appears before the one below it");
logger.info("[" + AUDIT_LOG_PREFIX + "] - User Details Updated by User : "+ r.getUserName());
```

The log output I get is as follows,

**operational.log**

```
2018-11-22 10:55:31 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-179] Just testing if this appears before the one below it (com.ssl.operational.action.EditDetailsActionBean)
```

**audit.log**

```
2018-11-22 10:58:51 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-192] Just testing if this appears before the one below it (com.ssl.operational.action.EditDetailsActionBean)
2018-11-22 10:58:51 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-192] [USER ACTION] - User Details Updated by User : adminuser
```

So really hoping that **audit.log** doesn't display the first log entry and just displays the one with USER ACTION string.

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated, Thank you

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. But not needed anymore. But still would be nice as someone might get into the same situation and come looking